# Adding photos to Anbox

Tags: android, anbox

How can i add photos to Gallery in Anbox Application Manager so I could post them to Reddit which i already managed to get? I have tried finding information about that but i don't see any matching results

Answer (score -1):

Not the most convenient way, but i just sent them to Reddit and then just saved to Android gallery.